# How do we send an array that contains text from an xml http request to PHP using mysqli?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is the code that is preparing my array, it will be sent as a parameter to the function that handles my HTTP request.

```
for (var i in the_texts) {
    if (the_texts[i]._status == "new") {
      var instance_texts_object = {};
      instance_texts_object._id = parseInt(the_texts[i]._id);
      instance_texts_object._data = encodeURIComponent(the_texts[i]._data);
      instance_texts_array.push(instance_texts_object);
    }
  } 
  the_texts.update_backend_text_instances_ajax(instance_texts_array);
```

An example of my instance_texts_array record looks like: `4: {_id: 3193, _data: "Click%20Me!"}`

My Ajax function looks like this:

```
update_backend_text_instances_ajax: function(texts_array_) {
    texts_array_ = JSON.stringify(texts_array_);
    var file_address = "includes/update_backend_texts_intances.php";
    var xhttp_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById('test_xml').innerHTML += "<br>" + "texts" + response;
      };
    };
    xhttp_request.open("POST", file_address + "?text_array=" + texts_array_, false);
    xhttp_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp_request.send();
  }
```

I am using a POST method.

My PHP script looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';
$text_array = $_REQUEST["text_array"];
$text_array_entry =  json_decode($text_array, true);
foreach($text_array_entry as $row) {
  $statement = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO the_texts (id, user_id, data) VALUES('".$row['_id']."', 600, '".$row['_data']."');");
};
echo print_r($text_array_entry);

 ?>
```

I think my problem is that my PHP script is not receiving my `text_array` variable. Disclaimer: `$connect` comes from `include_once 'database.php'`

Comment: Did you try ‘$_POST’ instead of ‘$_REQUEST’?

Comment: So when I try "$_POST" instead of "$_REQUEST" I get the error "Notice: Undefined index: text_array... on line 3" as well as the error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ... on line 5" @MoisheySchwartz

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz he's sending it in the query string, so it's actually in `$_GET`.

Comment: Your POST variables should go in xhttp_request.send()

Comment: If you think PHP is not receiving the data, first step would be to `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and see what comes out. If that looks ok, next step would be to `var_dump($text_array_entry);` and see what comes out.

Comment: @miken32 right, so he’s opening a POST but sending the variables as a query string

Comment: Can you give me an example of usage for "$_GET" or with "xhttp_request.send()?" Currently I am trying "$text_array = $_GET["text_array"];" on my PHP script as you suggested. @MoisheySchwartz

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz sending it as POST doesn't get rid of the $_GET variable or make it ignore the query string. You can use both at the same time. Ideally, it should be sent as POST, since it's performing a database update.

Comment: @FranciscoOchoa https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send there you can find POST and GET examples